# Stack calling destructor even after following the rule of three

Tags: c++

Everytime I push a object into my stack it calls it's destructor. I assume this is because it is making an tempobject, pushing it, then destroying the tempObject.

```
enum State{Empty, Main, Menu};

class StateInfo{
public: 
StateInfo(State state);
~StateInfo();
StateInfo(const StateInfo& otherState);
StateInfo& operator=(const StateInfo& otherState);
private:
std::string _stateType;
State _state;
};
```

The destructor just prints a message saying _stateType was destroyed. 
The copy and = functions just set _stateType and _state = to the otherState.

When I make a stack and push and object into it:

```
std::stack<StateInfo> _stateStack;
   _stateStack.emplace(StateInfo(State::Main));
```

I get a message saying the destructor was called.

Comment: `StateInfo(State::Main)` is going to be destroyed after its copied into the `stack`

Comment: Got it working, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should replace your statement to:

```
_stateStack.emplace(State::Main);
```

then object will be created in place passing `State::Main` to it's constructor. You explicitly created temporary `StateInfo` forcing copy or move ctor call (and destructor).

Answer (score 4):

You should pass the arguments to `State`'s constructor directly to `emplace()`:

```
_stateStack.emplace(State::Main);
```